# Configure htaccess to load static pages

Tags: .htaccess

Im working on a server with the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php
RewriteRule  ^[^/]*\.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)/.*$ - [L]
```

Now they asked me to prepare a static page inside their server, lets call it http://www.myserver.com/mystaticpage.html

The problem is that when i try to access that url, it redirects to index.php. How could I alter the htacces file to address this problem without messing anything with the installed CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

- The rules you used before were redundant: if `.*` is rewritten to index.php then why also rewrite `^[^/]*\.html$ index.php` to it? it already matched previous rule...
- They also overlapped - since the three `RewriteCond` conditions were only applied on the first rule. So the second rule was also applied to static files on disk.
- Also, the two rules that were listed last had no effect whatsoever. Either you needed to list them first, or not at all. I converted them to an additional `RewriteCond` since they were only attempted to avoid rewrite on certain uris